# Finding the difference between two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames say df1, df2 each has two columns `['Name', 'Marks']`

I want to find the difference between the two ifs for corresponding Name Values.

Eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Shivi",70],["Alex",40]],columns=['Names', 'Value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Shivi",40],["Andrew",40]],columns=['Names', 'Value'])
```

For df1-df2 I want

```
pd.DataFrame([["Shivi",30],["Alex",40],["Andrew",40]],columns=['Names', 'Value'])
```

Comment: Why is Stan -90?

Comment: As shown, they are nested lists, not DataFrames.

Comment: I didn't know how to make a df in markdown, just imagine that df1 and df2 are two ifs with those values

Comment: you may use `df.to_dict()` data to post in your question

Comment: What's wrong with `df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Ashley', 40],['Tom',50]])`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
diff = df1.set_index("Name").subtract(df2.set_index("Name"), fill_value=0)
```

So a complete program will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Name': ["Ashley", "Tom"], 'Marks': [40, 50]}
data2 = {'Name': ["Ashley", "Stan"], 'Marks': [80, 90]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

diff = df1.set_index("Name").subtract(df2.set_index("Name"), fill_value=0)

print(diff)
```

Output:

```
        Marks
Name
Ashley  -40.0
Stan    -90.0
Tom      50.0
```